# How does underdriving a powerful (eg. 50w, 100w) LED chip work?

Tags: power-supply, led, voltage, driver

My question concerns **under driving** an LED chip.

Unlike quality brand chips (Bridgelux, Cree), in my experience, under-driving non-brand ones make things more long lasting and favorable.

Using the potentiometer on my quality LED driver, I can lower or increase the Voltage to underdrive a typical 12v LED strip which comes with resistors etc.

My question:

- How can I underdrive a powerful 50w or 100w LED chip?
- Do I need to lower the voltage again, or is there any other way? (to run 50w chip on 35w, for example)

Comment: If you're using a 50 or 100W LED + driver, the current regulation should be provided by the driver. Lowering the *input* voltage to a regulated driver will only make life hard for the driver as it does its best to maintain full current (and it could overheat and thereby have its life foreshortened because the currents it has to deal with will increase). Similarly, adding resistance in series with the LED (assuming a current-regulated driver) will increase the driver currents, possibly leading to a truncated lifespan, without necessarily reducing the LED current.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany, if I am using a DC booster with 2 potentiometers to set Voltage & Current (to convert DC from 12v PSU to drive high-power LEDs), how would I set the voltage and current on the booster in this case? All LED chips I'm looking at give ranges for both voltage AND current. How do I find the sweet spot to adjust the potentiometers on the booster? Can you please shed some light on this as well?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany should I post this as a new question and provide link here? It sounds complex enough to merit its own page :)

Comment: Sure, you can make it its own question, but make sure there are links to the "DC booster" manual (schematic if available) and any other information that could be relevant. Only one parameter (voltage *or* current) can be regulated at once, the regulator regulates the other variable to control the one that's set. There may be a mode transition or transitions at some point(s). For example the regulator might try to control current to 750mA (by adjusting the voltage) but not let the voltage exceed 5V, and perhaps you shouldn't expect 750mA if the voltage is less than 2V.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LEDs are best regulated by controlling the current through them. Controlling the voltage across them can lead to excessive current flow and possibly killing the LED. See this typical V_I characteristic: -

[image]

Above is a typical LED (blue) lowish power LED characteristic. Note that with 2.3 volts applied hardly any current flows into the LED. If this voltage is increased to 2.7 volts, 20mA flows. Given the natural variations in the manufacturing process, it's difficult to control LED current based on assumptions about the forward V-I characteristic.

Even if you did get the voltage right, with high-power LEDs and their self-heating the characteristic might shift and what you thought was (say) 100mA rises up or falls back 50mA in a few minutes.

Best practice is to control the current fed to a LED either by a series resistor (low power applications) or a switching current regulator (higher powers).

Comment: So, if a constant V and constant C PSU is attached to an LED (but say PSU is 60w, LED is 100w), would it not damage the PSU?

Comment: If the power supply is set to deliver a constant current then that is what it will give. However, the voltage needs to be set high enough to overcome the likely forward voltage in the LED's characteristic and, if this is done correctly you'll notice that the voltage will fall a little to accommodate the correct current set on the power supply's constant current control.

Comment: Note that the question specifies "a typical 12v LED strip which comes with resistors etc." So, the current regulation is already adequately provided by the resistors.

Comment: @PhilFrost yes but then the OP went on to talk about testing with bare LED chips.